# how to fill a table with using some of the data of other tables

Tags: sql-server

I need to create a new table called “customer” that include some of columns from the “user table”, and also “project table”. I built my suppliers table with specific column names and I need to fill its column by using data of the other tables. Finally I am trying to finish; when user create a new account and project, the customer table automatically fill with some of other two tables varieties with different column names.

INFO: I have three different user types such as “suppliers”, “costumers”, “managers”. I am holding their information(include user types) in one table called users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following query as an example and write a query to insert the rows to destination table from source table.
Ex:-

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (FirstName, LastName)
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM Person.Contact
WHERE EmailPromotion = 2
```

Note: Use [`Join`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/join-tables-and-queries-HA010096320.aspx) in the select query to join two tables

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have 3 questions,
1- INSERT INTO TestTable (FirstName, LastName, ProjectName)
   SELECT FirstName, LastName, ProjectName
   FROM UserInfo, ProjectInfo
   WHERE UserType = 2
I guess ıt wont work :) how can use that query when I want to use two different table??

2- Will two queries work??

3- And is it dinamic?? I mean, will that query get data automatically when system has new users and projects or updates?

Comment: .@Egemn refer this site, you will know whether it will work or not.[Insert Vs Select][1]


  [1]: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/15/sql-server-insert-data-from-one-table-to-another-table-insert-into-select-select-into-table/

Answer (score 0):

The 1st step would be to couple the data from the different tables using a table join command.  If you can create a search result that matched your new table, then creating the table is simple a call to the below.

`Create table CUSTOMER as (Select ...)`

"when user create a new account and project.." this is something you plan on doing at run time in your application and not something you need to collate using sql at this point?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have different interfaceses that take information about users and project. At some point I need to show spesific informations(data) in ListViews(management panel*: which customer has which project, etc..). I cound't be able to create ListView that get datas with my requirements. There is allways misstakes such as updates and changes. Also I want to learn more prosedures and codeing in Sql Server. Anyway, I think I need to collate or whatever it calls by using sql for creating tables by my requirements. I guess it will be more dinamic solution.